# Restricting merge in Stash to main branch if SonarQube Code Quality gates fail for a project

Tags: git, sonarqube, bitbucket, git-merge, bitbucket-server

DEV branch - Dev env
MAIN branch - All higher envs

Currently we have a DEV branch in Stash for which we fail builds if Quality Gate thresholds are not met in SonarQube using the build breaker plugin

But we have also allowed DEV to skip the build breaker check.

As an additional check we wanted to restrict the merge in Stash from DEV to MAIN if the quality gates are not met. I know Stash allows some restrictions to be set while merging. But I'm not aware if I can do this based on SonarQube Quality Gate status for the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind a commercial plug-in you can achieve this with our Atlassian plug-in [Sonar for Bitbucket Server](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/ch.mibex.stash.sonar4stash/server/overview). The plug-in can do much more, but most noticeably it shows Sonar issues only on the diff between two branches.

Hope this helps.

Cheers,
Michael